# Auto Resize UITableViewCell when a view is added to it

Tags: dynamic, uitableview, autoresize

I have a table view where in each cell i want to add various fields dynamically as i fetch them from a web service. each cell will have different information represented by different fields.

My question is how do I set the height of the cell dynamically for each cell with different number of fields which gets added in my cell. Each field will be displayed using a label that will be added to the cell view.